# How to get gem commands to show up in application help message?

Tags: origen-sdk

I have a gem command that works when run in the spec tests.  However, I do not see the command show up in when the master application runs the `origen h` command. I used this [documentation](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/commands/) as my guide.  Here is the gem help command I created which is not working in the main app (only within the gem itself).

```
else
  # You probably want to also add the your commands to the help shown via
  # origen -h, you can do this by assigning the required text to @application_commands
  # before handing control back to Origen.
  @application_commands = <<-EOT
fetch_test_module <testmodule> --path <dir>
  EOT
end
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you link to covers how to add a command to an application, or in the case of a plugin, a command which is only available when running the plugin from its own workspace.
The process for integrating a plugin command which you want to make available to parent applications is slightly different.

You must declare an shared command launcher in the plugin's `config/application.rb` as shown here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/plugins/creating/#Sharing_Other_IP

Then create the shared command launcher as shown here: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/plugins/creating/#Sharing_Application_Commands

Once you do that, the command will show up in both the plugin's own workspace and the workspace of applications which include said plugin.